# how to upload multiple images and display on website using one button in Laravel

Tags: javascript

How to upload multiple images and show on webpage using one button in Larvel?

Means images are selected and uploaded with one button not two buttons.

Comment: Show us what you have tried or researched...

Answer (score 0):

You must create a migration to create the database table, the model and the form to manage the load process from the frontend side, and after making sure to validate the correct file type

```php
'filename' => 'required',
'filename.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:xxxx'
```

and finally, store the images in the database.

Follow this tutorial https://appdividend.com/2018/02/05/laravel-multiple-images-upload-tutorial/